# Building a Multidimensional Array Programmatically

Tags: php, arrays

It's probably not possible, and I'm damn fool.  But, I am trying to build an array in PHP, where some of the elements are variables.

```
$myArr = array();
$i = 1;
$n = 5;
for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
  if($i === 1){
      $myArr["k$i"] = array(
          'description' => 'Some special text for the k1 element',
          'type' => 'some type',
          'foo' => 'bar',
      )
  }else{
      $myArr["k$i"] = array(
          'description' => 'This is the number ' . $i . ' element description.'
          'type' => 'some type',
          'foo' => 'bar',
      )
  }
}
return $myArr;
```

The results should be:

```
$myArr = [
  k1 => [
    'description' => 'Some special text for the k1 element',
    'type' => 'some type',
    'foo' => 'bar',
  ],
  k2 => [
    'description' => 'This is the number 2 element description.'
  ...
  ],
] // ending bracket for the $myArr array
```

PHP complains most often about the curly-bracket closing the IF statement.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT

The suggestion to look at some long list of 'Common Syntax Errors' is not the answer, and not specific enough of an answer to help me in a timely manner.  Also, I simply did not FIND that solution while searching for answers to my question -- perhaps the 'Common Syntax Errors' solution is not properly tagged?

Also, I posted THIS question because the many other questions I managed to find and review, related to PHP arrays, never showed me how to handle variables WITHIN the array.  I posted MY question, with example code, in the hopes that a future coder might find how to handle variables WITHIN the array syntax.

Comment: You're missing semicolons after your two assignment statements before the closing curly brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @KevinY -- Thank you.  That was very helpful, and I do believe it was why  PHP was getting hung up on the curly-brace for the IF statement.  I would vote this comment up, but I don't see the option -- perhaps I do not have enough reputation on SO.  Anyway, thank again.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but you forgot semicolons and commas

```
$myArr = array();
$i = 1;
$n = 5;
for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
  if($i === 1){
      $myArr["k$i"] = array(
          'description' => 'Some special text for the k1 element',
          'type' => 'some type',
          'foo' => 'bar',
      );
  }else{
      $myArr["k$i"] = array(
          'description' => 'This is the number ' . $i . ' element description.',
          'type' => 'some type',
          'foo' => 'bar',
      );
  }
}
return $myArr;
```

Comment: I did find the missing comma within the array as well, thank you Vivek.  @KevinY 's comment above was the most helpful response.